# Drives missing from "This PC", yet they are Online and have a letter assigned

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I'm facing this issue where the drives don't appear in This PC under the Windows Explorer or a Search folder prompt.

All my drives are online, have a letter assigned and are fully accesible by manually typing the path (E:\something) or by apps (Steam can play games stored in my F:\ drive).

[image]

The only drive showing is a network attached SBC.

Does anyone know how to fix this strange issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally fixed it by manually editting two registry keys:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

If either one has a property named NoDrives with anything other than 0, change it to 0, then reboot and it should be fixed. It worked for me at least. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

I hope it helps somebody out there!

[Props to Neemobeer over at Windows Forum for finding the solution!](https://windowsforum.com/threads/drives-missing-from-this-pc-yet-they-are-online-and-have-a-letter-assigned.228849/#post-696772)

Answer (score -1):

There are several approaches to fixing this problem. The simplest is to

Go to **Control Panel**

Open **Administrative Tools**

Open **Computer Management**

Select **Storage**

Open **Disk Management**

Right click on the required drive and select **Change Drive Letter or Path**

**Add** the correct drive letter

Comment: The drives already have a correct drive letter. Removing and adding a new drive letter makes them appear, though. Adding back the old drive letter makes them dispersar again!

Comment: -1 because it's clear from the question that it had already been done and the question title says this explicitly.